# Regarding understanding the amplitude contained in a signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I just want to know and understand why the signal **`x1`** is of the highest amplitude while the signal **`x2`** has the lowest one as shown below in the image?

when I ran the code, I expected to see `x1` of the lowest amplitude, `x2` of the medium amplitude and `x3` has the highest amplitude, because, as shown in the equations below, `x1` is multiplied by 10 and `x2` equals `x1` plus another amplitude of 10 and so on.

kindly please clarify these points.

[image]

Comment: `x3` is comprised of three cosine signals with the same amplitude (10) but with different frequencies (3, 20 and 50 Hz). I think the differences in amplitude in the spectrogram are due to the data being discrete.

Answer (score 2):

The signal `x3` contains three cosines with the same amplitude but different frequencies. The spectrum should therefore ideally contain three dirac impulses with the same amplitude. This would only be the case if we had an infinitly long observation of the signals. We have "windowed" signal consisting of a number `L=8000` samples. You "cut out" the 8000 samples, which is like multiplying the signal with a rectangular signal. The spectrum of one rectangle is a sinc impulse consisting of a mainlobe and several smaller sidelobes.

The spectrum you will get for `x3` will therefore be the convolution of the 3 diracs with a sinc impulse. This is exactly what you get when plotting the DTFT:

[image]

The DFT is a sampled version of the DTFT. The `k` DFT frequencies [image] are defined as

[image]

where `N` is the length of the DFT. This is where your problem is: You calculate the DFT with `N=8192` and `fs=8000`. You will therefore not hit the exact frequencies `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. The nearest points to the "real" peaks will be

```
f1 = 2.9297 Hz
f2 = 19.5313 Hz
f3 = 49.8047 Hz
```

The peaks you see in the DFT are therefore smaller than they should be.

[image]

You also see that the largest difference between the real and the measured frequency, which is at `f2`, leads to the smallest peak in the DFT. The rounding error in frequencies remains less than [image], i.e. it decreases with increasing DFT length.

Long story short: For a periodic signal, you can adjust the DFT length to make sure, the DFT hits the real frequencies (as @gg349 suggested in his answer). In general, you can make the DFT length `N` longer to get a smaller rounding error and get closer to the DTFT. To get a better DTFT and thus increase the frequency resolution, you have to increase the data length `L`.

Comment: "This would only be the case if we had infinite samples of the signals". This is fundamentally wrong. As long as the signal is periodic, the DFT is a good tool for the job, and it will extract exactly the amplitudes of the harmonics. I think it is not the best idea to use a rectangular window for the purpose of discussing the amplitudes of the harmonics. And the final suggestion is not the best option, as you do not need many samples.

Comment: If you limit yourself to only periodic signals, your comments and your answer are correct and justified. The statements from my answer should work for any arbitrary signals. For clarification, by "infinite samples" I mean an infinitely long observation, not an infinite sampling frequency.

Comment: The question regards a periodic signal. You may want to clarify this

Answer (score 0):

`x1,x2,x3` have respectively 1,2 and 3 harmonics at 3 different frequencies, and all the harmonics have `10` as amplitude. When you study these signals in frequency domain, you are expecting `x1,x2,x3`to present respectively 1,2 and 3 peaks, and all the peaks to have the same amplitude. So `x1` has 1 peak at `3Hz` (assuming we talk about time here), and `x3` has 3 peaks, at the frequencies `3,20,50Hz`.

Despite what I just said, if you plot the absolute value of the fourier transform without choosing a specific observation window, you will find for example for `x3` that the heights of the 3 peaks at the 3 frequencies differ. This can be seen in your top right figure for `x3`, and also in @hbaderts's answer, which doesn't really address your question. This happens because your time vector `t` is not a multiple of the period of the signal, and this leads you to a signal `x3` (or `x1,x2` for the matter) that is NOT periodic (or at least is not periodic in the way you thought it would be), and you can't anymore expect the above to be respected, because many more frequency components will smear this picture.

Since you are generating the signal and not loading it from a sensor, you can change your observation window `t` so that the signal is periodic in that window. The required observation window in this case is `1` second (so that each of the periods `t1,t2,t3` is contained in `1s` an integer number of times). You can then choose a number of equispaced points between `t=0` and `t=1`, excluding the last point, i.e. in the range `[0,1)`.

The only thing left to discuss is the sampling frequency, that must be higher than twice the highest frequency of your signal. In this case the highest freq. is `fmax = 50`, so that we need to sample at above `fs=100Hz` in order to resolve all the harmonics. We also need the sampling frequency to be a natural number, or the discrete points between `0` and `1` will not be equispaced and the signal will not be periodic.

An example follows in python, leaving to you to adjust it in Matlab:

```
from numpy import arange, cos
from numpy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1, f2, f3 = 3., 20., 50.  # in Hz
T1, T2, T3 = 1 / f1, 1 / f2, 1 / f3
T_all = 1
# From Shanon theoreom we must use a sampling freq. larger than this:
f_sample = 2 * max([f1, f2, f3])
# we also need to use an integer sampling frequency, or the
# points will not be equispaced between 0 and 1. We then add +1 to f_sample:
dt = 1 / (f_sample + 1)
t = arange(0, T_all, dt)
# another way of generating the points, without fixing the sampling frequency
# follows. In this case one must check that 1 / dt > f_sample afterwards
# t, dt = linspace(0, T_all, 2000, endpoint=False, retstep=True)
x3 = 1 * cos(2 * pi * f1 * t) + 2 * cos(2 * pi * f2 * t) + 3 * cos(2 * pi * f3 * t)

y = rfft(x3)
freqs = rfftfreq(t.size, d=dt)  # in Hz

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # we plot the abs. value of the fft:
# the factor 2/t.size is the normalizing factor between peaks
# of the DFT and original amplitudes in time domain.
ax.plot(freqs, 2 * abs(y) / t.size, 'o')
ax.set_ylim(0, 3.5)
ax.set_xlabel('f  [Hz]')
ax.grid()
fig.show()
```

We find that the discrete DFT shows in fact a non-zero value only at the designated frequencies. By rescaling appropriately the result, we also recover the exact amplitude of the harmonics, chosen in this example to be `1,2,3`.
[image]
For reference, I report the original time-signal, at the minimum sampling rate as in the code above, i.e. at `f_sample+1` Hz. Moreover, the sampling frequency must be 1) larger than `f_sample` to avoid undersampling, and respect Shannon's theorem; 2) an integer number, to have evenly distributed discrete samples between `0s` and `1s`, i.e. in order to have a periodic signal.

Notice how the last point at t=1 is missing:
[image]